# ASP.NET C# Dynamic Element Styling and Events

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I am currently dynamically generating ASP elements on a website. The site displays items for a specific motorcycle based on the make/model/year.

**Issue 1:** I have all of the items displaying correctly, on the page, but I cannot figure out how to get my CSS styling to apply to the dynamically generated items.

Heres what I have, it querys the items into a datatable first:

```
try
{
  int tempflag = 0;
  foreach (DataRow tempRow in dt.Rows)
  {
    string tempCategory = tempRow[4].ToString();
    string tempPartUrl = tempRow[5].ToString();
    string tempImageUrl = tempRow[6].ToString();
    string tempPartBrand = tempRow[7].ToString();
    string tempPartName = tempRow[8].ToString();
    string tempPrice = tempRow[9].ToString();
    string tempStoreName = tempRow[10].ToString();

    //panel to hold an item
    Panel pnlItem = new Panel();
    pnlItem.ID = "id_pnItem_" + tempflag;
    pnlItem.CssClass = "itemDiv";
    divSearchResultsBody.Controls.Add(pnlItem);

    //image
    Image tpImg = new Image();
    tpImg.ID = "id_tpImg_" + tempflag;
    tpImg.ImageUrl = tempImageUrl;
    pnlItem.Controls.Add(tpImg);

    Label lblBR = new Label();
    lblBR.ID = "frt" + tempflag;
    lblBR.Text = "<br />";
    pnlItem.Controls.Add(lblBR);

    //brand
    Label lblBrand = new Label();
    lblBrand.ID = "id_lblBrand_" + tempflag;
    lblBrand.Text = tempPartBrand;
    pnlItem.Controls.Add(lblBrand);

    //name
    Label lblName = new Label();
    lblName.ID = "id_lblName_" + tempflag;
    lblName.Text = tempPartName;
    pnlItem.Controls.Add(lblName);

    //price
    Label lblPrice = new Label();
    lblPrice.ID = "id_lblPrice_" + tempflag;
    lblPrice.Text = tempPrice;
    pnlItem.Controls.Add(lblPrice);

    //url
    HyperLink hyp = new HyperLink();
    hyp.ID = "id_link_" + tempflag;
    hyp.NavigateUrl = tempPartUrl;
    hyp.Text = "View Part";
    pnlItem.Controls.Add(hyp);
    tempflag++;              
  }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  handleTheError(ex);
}
```

I'm not sure how to access my css sheet from the .aspx.cs. so all the elements are just smashed together one after another each in a panel.

**Issue 2:** I am also generating checkboxes based on the item's category's so I can create a filter. I grab distinct categories with a query and fill them into a datatable. I have all the checkboxes but I have no idea how to go about generating an event for them because they are dynamic, and I've only used events that are hard coded. The code is similar:

```
foreach (DataRow tempRow in dt2.Rows)
{
  string tempCategory = tempRow[0].ToString();
  CheckBox cbCategory = new CheckBox();
  cbCategory.ID = "id_cbCategory_" + tempflag2;
  cbCategory.Text = tempCategory;
  divFilterCategory.Controls.Add(cbCategory);

  tempflag2++;
}
```

**Issue 3:** There are two divs that are next to each other, one for filter results that are generated, and another for the item results that are generated. As I mentioned they both generate properly at the moment, but for some reason when the items generate it shoots the second div halfway down the page. Pics:Before searching, After searching, Filters halfway down the page
[image]

[image]

[image]

Heres what the initial design looks like

```
<div runat="server" id="divSearch" class="divCenterItems">
    <table class="searchTable">
        <tr style="width: 100%">
            <td style="width: 29%">
                <div runat="server" id="divSearchFiltersHeader" class="divSearchHeaders">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFilterResults" Text="Filter Results" CssClass="headerLabels"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div runat="server" id="divSearchFiltersBody">
                    <div runat="server" id="divFilterCategory"></div>
                    <div runat="server" id="divFilterBrand"></div>
                    <div runat="server" id="divFilterPrice"></div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 69%">
                <div runat="server" id="divSearchResultsHeader" class="divSearchHeaders">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSearchTitle" Text="Search Results Title" CssClass="headerLabels"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div runat="server" id="divSearchResultsBody">
                    <div runat="server" id="divItemsMSS"></div>
                    <div runat="server" id="divItemsRMATVMC"></div>
                    <div runat="server" id="divItemsDK"></div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
.divCenterItems
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.searchTable
{
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.divSearchHeaders
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url('../Resources/header.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 30px;
}
.headerLabels 
{
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Im not sure if any of these styles would be causing the filter div to act like this, but I've been playing around with them with no success. Any tips for tricks for these types of situations would be greatly appreciated, I'm new to dynamically generating elements. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**Issue 1**:

Consider Using the [Literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal(v=vs.110).aspx) Web Control and putting html elements inside of the text with your desired classes.

```
        var ltl = new Literal();
        ltl.ID = "id_ltlName_" + tempFlag;
        ltl.Text = $"<div class='class1'>{tempRow[1]}></div><div>{tempRow[2]}";
        pnlItem.Controls.Add(ltl);
```

You could also create an ascx user control, and load instances of that dynamically if you want more functionality inside of the panel.

**Issue 2**
To add events to a dynamically created control, use the += operator to add a handler to be called when the event is fired. For Example, to handle the CheckChanged event for a checkbox. Remember that with dynamic controls, these event handlers have to be registered on every postback.

```
var checkbox1 = new CheckBox();
checkbox1.CheckedChanged += ClickedCheckBox;

private void ClickedCheckBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var checkbox1 = sender as CheckBox;
}
```

**Issue 3**
You have 2 tds next to each other. Try vertical-align:top on both of them

```
<div runat="server" id="divSearch" class="divCenterItems">
    <table class="searchTable">
        <tr style="width: 100%">
            <td style="vertical-align:top;width: 29%;">
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align:top;width: 69%">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: For Issue 1, I tried using Literals and it adds them all to the page in code, but they dont actually show up on the page, its odd. I can copy and paste the code it generates and it works pefectly, but It wont work through this auto generation. I tried Server.HtmlDecode and then adding them through that, but It did nothing for me.

For Issue 2 I tried your suggested method but it doesnt seem to ever hit the ClickedCheckBox() when I step through it. 

For Issue 3, It worked perfectly! Thanks a lot!